# Java GNOME bindings, are those a good idea?

Tags: java, swing, toolkit

What do you think of Java's [GNOME bindings](http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/) and I was surprised to know that the latest version of the bindings was released [this month](http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/4.0/NEWS.html) and they're backed by a company that uses them, which means that there's a considerable amount of activity in the project, and that it's not going to be ditched anytime soon

Is this going to be a second chance for Java on the desktop, since GTK+ is cross platform like swing, but less bloated and more responsive

Should I be learning how to develop applications using it? or it's not worth the time?

Comment: Is this dependent on just GTK or does it require GNOME? Because if relies on the latter, then its not cross platform.

Comment: I think they also ported GTK+, I'm not sure, but the GTK+ libraries are there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in general developers who prefer Java are already using it, and those who prefer Gtk+ are using C or C++.  It's a pretty small intersection of developers who both prefer Java *and* Gtk+.

Swing isn't dead, though.  Of the 6 cross-platform apps I use regularly, 2 are swing, 2 are Gtk+, one is Tcl/Tk, and one uses a "native" toolkit on every platform.  Although the Java apps take a few more seconds to startup, in normal operation the difference in GUI responsiveness is negligible.  Certainly not noticeable enough to convince someone to switch on that basis alone.  The only benefit I can see is if you have a group of programmers that frequently switch back and forth between Java and C for other reasons.

Comment: The only swing-based app I know is netbeans, the rest are not as popular, I guess